# I want to update an entry in my database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Hi I want to update an entry in my DB , I am giving my codes for the updateEntry function below..I want to update the password field I have tried something but it is not working

```
 public String updateEntry(String Password) {
    // Create object of content values
    ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
    // Assign values for each item
    // updatedValues.put("USERNAME", User_name);
    updatedValues.put("PASSWORD", Password);

    String where = "PASSWORD=?";
    db.update("LOGINDETAILS", updatedValues, where,
            new String[] { Password });
    return Password;
}
```

and this is the code I have written to update the entry :

```
String Passwordnew =loginDataBaseAdapter.updateEntry(Confirm_password);
     Passwordnew=Confirm_password;
```

where I want update the password in DB with the confirm_password. I need some good suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format your question so we can read it, thanks.

Comment: just a general advice. variable-names in java NEVER start with a capital letter!

Comment: The problem in your code is: What's the entry do you want to update? Follow your code, you want  to update to PASSWORD=Password??? No, it's not correct. I suggest you change where condition to update the right entry, maybe USERNAME = "what_ever"

Answer (score 3):

```
public int UpdateContact(int id,String username,String password) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(USERNAME, username); 
    values.put(PASSWORD, password); 


    // updating Row
    return db.update(LOGINDETAILS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { id });


}
```

call this database function to your Activity

```
db.UpdateContact("1","dhaval","1234");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int updateProfile(GetSet profile) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ID, profile.getUniqueID());
    values.put(NAME, profile.getName());
    values.put(EMAIL, profile.getEmail());
    values.put(DOB, profile.getDob());
    values.put(PHONE, profile.getPhone());
    values.put(PLACE, profile.getPlace());
    // db.close();
    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { profile.getUniqueID() });

}
```

In the corresponding activity:

```
RemoteDatabase remote = new RemoteDatabase(this);
GetSet profile;




 profile = new GetSet(setname, seteid, setphone, setplace,
                        setdob);

                profile.setUniqueID(sdumid);
                remote.updateProfile(profile);
                remote.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Logic needs correction, Don't use Password for where clause, use field that is the primary key for your database, maybe username or an auto-increment id.

Then you can update using following code:

```
public boolean update(int id,String username,String password)
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    String where = id+"=?";

    cv.put(USERNAME, username); 
    cv.put(PASSWORD, password); 

    return db.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, where,new int[] { id })>0;
 }
```